# Why NSConfinementConcurrencyType is obsolete?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have background task (created using `NSOperationQueue` or GCD) and it fetches some data periodically and sends it to remote server.

I can't use `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` not only because main run loop may freeze but also because I am on different thread and context is not thread-safe.

I do not want to use `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` because I do not need new separate thread  (I already have one!) and this type also requires `performBlockAndWait:` that makes my code look like spaghetti:)

So, I use `NSConfinementConcurrencyType` in synchronous way, from my own thread, and it works! but comment says `NSConfinementConcurrencyType` is obsolete and exists only for backward compatibility.

Why? Which type should I use for my case?

Answer (score 0):

Main idea is that you don’t need operation queues anymore with new concurency types and you don’t need context merging. Also, new concurency types gives you parent-child relationships. More is clearly described by [Olivier Drobnik](https://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/).

Comment: Thank you, I know about parent/child context and I use it, but what is wrong with operation queues? Should I use private queue context and do all by HTTP requests in its ``performBlock``?